# Average of images using Magick.NET

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I can blend/average two images using ImageMagick with the following command:

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg ... N.jpg -average result.jpg
```

or alternatively

```
convert *.jpg -evaluate-sequence mean result.jpg
```

I'm looking for a way to do this in C#, how can I do this using Magick.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, following should work:

```
using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
  // Add the first image
  MagickImage first = new MagickImage("Snakeware.png");
  images.Add(first);

  // Add the second image
  MagickImage second = new MagickImage("Snakeware.png");
  images.Add(second);

  // Create an Average from both images
  using (MagickImage result = images.Evaluate(EvaluateOperator.Mean))
  {
    // Save the result
    result.Write("Mean.png");
  }
}
```

[Merge multiple images.](https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Combining%20images)

[MagickImageCollection.h](https://magick.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Magick.NET/MagickImageCollection.h)

[`EvaluateOperator`](https://magick.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Magick.NET/Enums/EvaluateOperator.h) Evaluate options

Comment: Thank you, I already got the mosaic exapmple from the documentation, but it doesn't average images. Mosaic overlays the images over one another and only the top image is visible. Averaging would be the equivalent of making he top image 50% transparent. I already looked through all the functions available for MagickImageCollection, didn't find one that fits.

Comment: Evaluate is perfect, Thank you. For averaging I used `MagickImage result = images.Evaluate(EvaluateOperator.Mean)`